# How to config moment not show: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I'm using moment to check time is valid or invalid.

```
const timeValid = moment(time).isValid();
```

It's working fine, but when time is invalid, moment thrown an Error to terminal as a below

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
> Blockquote
>
> Arguments:
> [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 1994-05-151, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

But I just want the result timeValid.
How I can turn off warning of moment.

Comment: Do you know the format of the time in advance? Or could it be in any format?

Comment: @TerryLennox The time is any string, But I want to moment not show warning, because I did using method isValid() to check input is date, valid date or not a date. I just want isValid() return true or false, no need to show warnig

Comment: `IsValid` tells you that the input represents a valid date and time.  In other words, it will tell you there is no June 31st, or that there's no 25:00. It isn't meant to be a general purpose "is this random string a date or time" function, even though it is used that way sometimes.